# ckam git clone related It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine

Tags: backend, ckan

when i try to install the ckan git clone it sayis like on this image

[image: 1]

ERROR: Cannot uninstall 'blinker'. It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partial uninstall

Comment: Hy, welcome to Stack Overflow, please [don't upload text, table or error message as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557). 
Edit your question to contain all the information in text form - consider to use the editor's formatting options. 
Also see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)